# Información disco duro remoto

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy intentando obtener la información de un disco duro remoto, en cuanto a espacio disponible y espacio total. Para ello tengo el siguiente fragmento de código

```
                ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath()
            {
                NamespacePath = @"root\cimv2",
                Server = "66.66.66.66"
            };
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(path);
            string condition = "DriveLetter = 'C:'";
            string[] selectedProperties = new string[] { "FreeSpace" };
            SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_Volume", condition, selectedProperties);

            using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
            using (ManagementObjectCollection results = searcher.Get())
            {
                ManagementObject volume = results.Cast<ManagementObject>().SingleOrDefault();

                if (volume != null)
                {
                    ulong freeSpace = (ulong)volume.GetPropertyValue("FreeSpace");

                    // Use freeSpace here...
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

Capturando la siguiente excepción
"El servidor RPC no está disponible"

Alguna alternativa?

Answer (score 0):

Existen varios puntos que podrias validar

- revisa que el servicio wmi en la pc remota este habilitado

  [Starting and Stopping the WMI Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/starting-and-stopping-the-wmi-service)
- valida que el firewall de la pc remota permita el acceso al puerto tcp que requiere wmi

  [Setting up a Remote WMI Connection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/connecting-to-wmi-remotely-starting-with-vista)

[How to troubleshoot RPC, WMI, Access Denied or Network Path Not Found errors in CCS](https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH227214.html)